# Mysql query for select data within 5,10 minit and 1,2 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two date one is entry_user and exit_user i want display count of number of user spend time in showroom from last 5 minit , last 30 minit and last 1 hours..I want to make this result from mysql query

Please Suggest me to how i do this for display below result

thanks advance

i want result like this

```
date        visitor_count

5 (minit)     4
10(minit)     10
1(hours)      20
```

my table example:

Comment: can you add table here?

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and [edit] your question.

Comment: ok...friends i add

Comment: What is data type of your `date` column?

Comment: datatype: varchar

Comment: i have posting a screen shoot of my table you can check

Comment: Dont give screenshot. Create text tables, preferably ASCII tables and give your expected output based on that.

Comment: Is it possible to change data type of your `date` column to [Integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) (minutes or seconds) or [Date and Time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)?

Comment: yes possible to make datetime datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create auxiliary table `intervals`, and add to this your time intervals in seconds. For example

```
CREATE TABLE `intervals` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `analytics`.`intervals` (`value`) VALUES(0),(300),(600),(1800),(3600);
```

To display count of user number accordinging to duration of an user activity use following:

```
SELECT 
  `value` AS `Duration`, COUNT(*) AS `visitor_count`
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(exit_user)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(entry_user) AS `Interval`
  FROM
    YourTable
  ) AS `Calculations` 
  JOIN intervals ON `Calculations`.`Interval` >= intervals.value
GROUP BY intervals.value
```

If you also want to group users by date of visit, then use

```
SELECT 
  `Date`, `value` AS `Duration`, COUNT(*) AS `visitor_count`
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    DATE(`entry_user`) AS `Date`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`exit_user`)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`entry_user`) AS `Interval`
  FROM
    YourTable
  ) AS `Calculations` 
  JOIN intervals ON `Calculations`.`Interval` >= intervals.value
GROUP BY `Calculations`.`Date`, intervals.value
```

Comment: i think your answer is right ... it works.. just one simple change that i want to display sum of per date visited user

Comment: Do you want to group users by duration and by date?

Comment: my friend i have visitor count column and value of this count will be always 1 and i want display count by group by date

Comment: hii ..  i want display display visitor_count sum of day...like current day i have three visitor then display 3 count and i have also visitor_count column and default entry by per visit on this column is 1

Comment: I create [Self-Contained file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiuPE6zx2HAWgYUNvsOX6oi7fGb4rg) for you. Import this file to your server and try.

Comment: Did you get the download file? Did one helps you?

Comment: A file gives an error .. on import to mysql    (#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Comment: Oh, there was my mistake! I have updated file. Please, download the file anew and use `user_count` and `user_count_2` views. Keep me informed.

Comment: Now this error appear my friend ...#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: ok, I have created a separate view for subquery in the FROM clause. Try again, please.

Comment: my friends..  it's imported but still no tables display ..that you define in file

Comment: Did you update schemas? In my server this is imported fine.

Comment: @Kiransuthar I have create new answer post for you. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Let there exists the table `sessions` with columns `entry_user` and `exit_user`. For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sessions`;
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_user` datetime NOT NULL,
  `exit_user` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `sessions` (entry_user, exit_user) 
VALUES 
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:00:10'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:03:00'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 01:00:00'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:07:00'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:15:03'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:06:00'),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:11:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-01 00:11:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-01 00:01:30');
```

Create auxiliary table `ticks`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticks`;
CREATE TABLE `ticks` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and add time ticks values in seconds:

```
INSERT INTO `ticks` (`value`) VALUES (0),(300),(600),(900),(1800),(3600);
```

Create view `intervals`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `intervals`;
CREATE VIEW intervals AS 
SELECT 
    s.`value` AS started, f.`value` AS finished 
FROM 
    ticks s JOIN ticks f ON s.ID = (f.ID - 1);
```

Now you can count sessions that durations more then specified ticks values, using

```
SELECT 
  `Date`, `value` AS `Duration more or equals then`, COUNT(*) AS `Visitors Number`
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    DATE(entry_user) AS `Date`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(exit_user)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(entry_user) AS Duration
  FROM
    sessions
  ) AS Durations 
  JOIN ticks ON Durations.Duration >= ticks.`value`
GROUP BY Durations.`Date`, ticks.`value`;
```

If you want to get density function of the session duration, use following:

```
SELECT 
  `Date`, started AS `Duration more or equals then`, finished AS `and less or equals then`, COUNT(*) AS `Visitors Number`
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    DATE(entry_user) AS `Date`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(exit_user)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(entry_user) AS Duration
  FROM
    sessions
  ) AS Durations 
  JOIN intervals ON Durations.Duration BETWEEN intervals.started AND intervals.finished
GROUP BY Durations.`Date`, intervals.`started`;
```

Comment: my friend ..i have found they solution with another tricky .method .. i also thank to you for give a best answer ..and i have also learned more from you... thank you very much my friend..and your answer is also works